# How to serve an image using nodejs reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I want to display images in the frontend. Images was saved in PostgreSQL database with a static path. I'm trying to set up an Express server to serve these images, but it's not working.

Here code:

**productCard**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../config/axios";
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";

function ProductCard() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/product");
        setProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching product data:", error);
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {products?.map((el) => {
        return (
          <ProductItem
            key={el?.id}
            src={el?.img}
            name={el?.name}
            description={el?.description}
            price={el?.price}
            file={el?.file}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductCard;
```

**productItem**

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "antd";
const { Meta } = Card;

function ProductItem({ name, description, price, file }) {
  console.log(file);
  return (
    <>
      <Card
        hoverable
        style={{ width: 240 }}
        cover={<img alt="example" src={file} />}
      >
        <Meta title={name} description={description} />
        <p className="mt-2 flex justify-end">{price}</p>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductItem;
```

*This is what i got when i log file:*

```
1696953634614-281617729calendar1.jpg
1696953636442-290084764calendar1.jpg
1696953636442-290084764calendar1.jpg
```

**server**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParse = require("body-parser");

const authRoute = require("./routes/authRoute");
const productRoute = require("./routes/productRoute");
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParse.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
app.use("/assets", express.static("/assets"));
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/", authRoute);
app.use("/api", productRoute);
app.use("/users", userRoute);

app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

How fo tix it? Thank you

---

***Problem solved with this:***

```
src={`http://localhost:8000/assets/${file}`}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you were at this for a while, it may be more appropriate to write an answer rather than just editing your question to include the answer.  It's fair game to provide an answer to your own question - especially if it went largely unanswered for a period of months like this.  Make sure you provide detail to your answer though - even though it's just for you.  e.g. Why does your solution solve the problem?

Comment: Also, for the future, be aware that "it's not working" is never a sufficiently detailed description of what when wrong when you tried.  Make sure your question describes steps to reproduce with expected vs actual results and/or any error messages that you got.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new here and newbie coding. you mean adding the answer in the comments right?. As for explaining why it works, I'm not sure if it actually works or why. So, I haven't written it down. I'll write it when I'm sure. btw, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you serve your files from “/assets” path, then you need to use the correct path in your ProductItem component

```
<img alt="example" src={`/assets/${file}`} />
```

Comment: its not working :((

Comment: i try this src={`http://localhost:8000/assets/${file}`} it works

Comment: Good! It works for you

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your Express server to send the base path where the images are stored as part of the API response. Then, in your React frontend, you can use this base path to construct the full URL for each image.